# Obtener detalles de item por id en ionic

Tags: array, angular, ionic, get, id

Tengo un problema al mostrar mis datos devueltos por una app mediante id la cual muestra el array en consola de que encontró el dato con el mismo id pero no se muestra en la vista

este es mi .ts
La función áreas obtiene todos y los muestra de manera correcta la vista pero la función areaID() solo muestra el array en consola del navegador
Al dar clic en un botón que lista todos los elementos obtengo el id después ese ideal lo paso por params con router link y asi le llega a la otra pagina

```
     areas(){
        this.áreasService.getAllArea().then((res)=>{
          this.area=this.áreasService.area.area
          // this.area =this.áreasService.area.area;
          console.log(this.area);
        }), err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
        areaID(id){
          this.áreasService.getArea(id).then((res)=>{
            this.area=this.áreasService.area.area
            // this.area =this.áreasService.area.area;
            console.log(this.area);
            
          }), err => {
              console.log(err);
          }}
    ngOnInit() {
      this.areas()
      const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
 this.areaID(id)
    }
}
```

Mi servicio donde tengo el listado general y listado por id

```
 getAllArea( ){
const path = 'http://localhost:3000/area'
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  this.http.get(path).subscribe(res=>{
    this.area=res;
    resolve();
  },error =>{
    console.log(error);
    reject();
      });
    });
  
  }
  getArea(id ){
    console.log(id);
    const path = 'http://localhost:3000/area/'
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      this.http.get(path + `${id}`).subscribe(res => {

        this.area=res;
        resolve();
      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
        reject();
          });
        });
      }
```

Bloque de código que paso mi id mediante routerLink a la pagina de detalles

```
 <div *ngFor="let areas of area">
        <div>
            <img HSPACE="10" class="shortcuts" src="assets/imagenes/áreasdisponibles.jpg" routerLink='/areasdisponibles' />
            <h2 class="link-to">{{areas.nombre}}</h2>
            <br><br>
          
            <ion-button routerLink='/areasdisponibles/{{areas._id}}'> Ver mas detalles
            </ion-button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Y esta es código de la pagina de detalles, intente simplemente mostrando un for como en la pagina que los muestra de manera general pero no funciono después intente con un if y tampoco

```
    <div *ngFor="let areas of area">

        <div *ngIf="areas._id == [id]">
            <h2 class="link-to">{{areas._id}}</h2>
            <h2 class="link-to">{{areas.nombre}}</h2>
            <h2 class="link-to">{{areas.Descripcion}}</h2>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Por ultimo esta es la imagen de los resultados en consola del navegador[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando consultas la api para obtener un detalle, te devuelve solamente un objeto, por eso es que no puedes usar el ngFor y te devuelve ese error.

Solo accede a las propiedades del objeto guardado en la variable `area`:

```
 <h2 class="link-to">{{area._id}}</h2>
 <h2 class="link-to">{{area.nombre}}</h2>
 <h2 class="link-to">{{area.Descripcion}}</h2>
```